# Angular 2 + IIS on refresh 404 error

Tags: angular, visual-studio-2015, iis-7.5, angular2-routing

I recently stated a angular 2 project in vs2015 and IIS 7.5.
I have a problem with refreshing pages, when I refresh a page i get

> "HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found".

And here is my angular code:
In index.html I have

```
<script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
```

In app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './components/home/home.component';

import { HomeModule } from './modules/home.module';
import { CodesModule } from './modules/codes.module';
import { AdminModule } from './modules/admin.module';

@NgModule({
    imports:
    [
        BrowserModule,
        HttpModule,
        RouterModule.forRoot([
            { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
            { path: 'home/:unauthorized', component: HomeComponent },
            { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },
            { path: '**', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },
        ]),
        HomeModule,
        CodesModule,
        AdminModule
    ],
    declarations:
    [
        AppComponent,
        HomeComponent
    ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

And the other moduls:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { CodesComponent } from '../components/codes/codes.component';

@NgModule({
    declarations:
    [
        CodesComponent
    ],
    imports:
    [
        RouterModule.forChild([
            { path: 'codes', component: CodesComponent },
        ])
    ]
})
export class CodesModule {

}

import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { AdminCompoment } from '../components/admin/admin.component';

@NgModule({
    declarations:
    [
        AdminCompoment
    ],
    imports:
    [
        RouterModule.forChild([
            { path: 'admin', component: AdminCompoment },
        ])
    ]
})
export class AdminModule {

}
```

When I try with hash tag works correctly, but I don't want to use has tag.
I tried rewrite rules in IIS but then when I refresh some page I have only redirect is to main page.

Please for help.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved.
 Steps:

1. Add rewrite in web.config
   with action like this
   `<action type="Rewrite" url="/eUsluge.Administration.UI/" appendQueryString="true" />`
2. Index.html add this

> `<base href="/Application/" />`

Comment: hi, where in the web.config is this supposed to be added?

Comment: Here
<rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="AngularJS" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" pattern="" ignoreCase="false" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" negate="true" pattern="^\/api\/.*$" ignoreCase="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="Here" appendQueryString="true" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
   
  </system.webServer>

Comment: What is the value 'eUsluge.Administration.UI' and where does it come from?